# Add callback to the class or individual elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I use JQuery, and I have a collection of buttons all of which have class `btnClass`. Some (or all) of them are toggled visible/invisible *repeatedly* based on some changing condition.

I want to add a callback to the click event when any of these buttons are clicked. I have two options:

1. Add a callback to all of them statically and upfront using the class selector: `$(".btnClass").on("click", function(e) { ... });`
2. Or add a callback dynamically and individually when a button is toggled visible: `btn.toggle(true).on("click", function(e) { ... });`

Performance wise, which is better and why? Is there some other approach that is better than both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance wise, use event delegation. It will have loads better performance compared to either of those options because a single handler is only attached once, on a known and existing parent element.

Similar to the example provided in the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation:

```
$("#wrapper").on("click", ".btnClass:visible", function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Agreed. And you can use ".btnClass:visible" in the delegation.